# PHP: SQL returns empty cells for non-empty fields

Tags: php, sql, join, left-join

I am calling a simple JOIN SQL on a mySQL database. The exact query called from the PHP script is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM weighteventtest 
LEFT JOIN commenttest ON weighteventtest.eventid=commenttest.eventid 
ORDER BY weighteventtest.eventid DESC
```

When I run the sql query directly in phpMyAdmin, I get a normal result set with all values. But when the script is called through PHP, the '`eventid`' field is empty or null for nearly all rows. When I echo the values of each row, all fields have a value except the primary key '`eventid`', which is empty, EXCEPT FOR the rows where there is a match on the joined table.

Any ideas?
thanks!
Will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is combining SELECT * with PHP.  Because there are *two* eventid fields in the output (one from each table) when you access the column by name (eventid) it's erroneously finding the second one (the NULL one from the missing right-side record).

To fix the problem, explicitly specify which columns you want after SELECT.  Use of SELECT * in production code is generally considered a bad practice in any event.

Comment: If you join with USING (eventid), it may clear up the problem.  It's a cleaner syntax when you have 2 tables with the same key.

Comment: The syntax you use will probably not have any effect on the list of columns in the result set (even assuming the user's DB supports USING — he did not specify what product he is using).

Comment: that sounds like it might fix my problem... will modify fields now and let you know asap...

Comment: Yep, that solved it. Thank you so much, @Larry Lustig! Once again, Stack Overflow saves the day. You people are marvelous!